# How to fix the size of a table so that on resizing the browser page the cells don't squeeze?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML using angularjs & twitter bootstrap for my table.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="overflow:auto">
    <table class="table table-striped" style="table-layout:fixed">
        <tr ng-repeat='(key,val) in arr' class="row">
            <td class="span1" style="width:150px;">
                    <h4>{{key}}</h4> 
            </td>
            <td class="span1" style="width:150px;" ng-repeat='(nestedKey,nestedVal) in val'>    <a href='{{nestedVal}}' target="_blank">{{nestedKey}}
                    <br>
                    <img src='{{nestedVal}}' style="width: 150px; height: 75px;" class="img-rounded"/>
                    </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

However the `overflow:scroll` creates a dummy scroll bar which never activates. Whenever I resize the browser, my images become really small and squeezed tight as well as overlapping on top of each other.

What is going wrong?

Comment: use css `min-width` on the table

Comment: @entre could you include the code snippet to show how to do that?

Comment: `<table style="min-width: 300px; overflow : auto" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `min-width` css attribute on the table, causing the table to remain a certain minimum width when the screen is smaller:

```
table{
   min-width:800px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also adapt the layout / width of your table with `CSS media queries` for mobile views:

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px){
  /* your table specific query here */
}
```

The quickest for you would be solution 1